# Access JavaScript cookie in module file

Tags: hooks, javascript, cookies

I am setting a cookie in an external JavaScript file with the current user time.
I want this time to be available to the server, so I am retrieving this from a cookie.

I am able to fetch the value, but only when I refresh the browser twice. If I change my current system time, and refresh the page, I still see the old time; when I refresh again, then I see the updated time.

#### JavaScript code

```
var now=new Date();
currTime=now.getHours();
document.cookie = "currentTime = " +currTime;
```

#### PHP code

```
$current_time = $_COOKIE["currentTime"];
echo $current_time;
```

I am calling the external JavaScript file in `hook_nodeapi()` using `drupal_add_js()`.

As I said, I am able to get the updated value of current time from cookie but only if I refresh twice.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I understood the problem. It is because the first time it sets the cookie, and in the second time it becomes available to PHP; hence two refreshes.